# Wordpress, get_current_user_id() returns 0 in a standalone php file

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my standalone php file

```
<?php
include('wp-blog-header.php');
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); 

global $wpdb; $user_id ;
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
echo $user_id;
?>
```

The php is giving the result as 0. Even if I am logged in with Id 1.

Answer (score 0):

Include the `wp-load.php` file in place of `wp-blog-header.php` with correct path.

```
<?php
include('wp-load.php');

global $wpdb; $user_id ;
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
echo $user_id;
?>
```

Comment: It still gives me 0. And my php file is located in the same location where wp-load.php exist.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your exact code on my system and it works as expected so there is nothing wrong with the code itself. Can you try

```
 <?php
include('wp-blog-header.php');
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); 
var_dump( $_COOKIE );
global $wpdb; $user_id ;
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
echo $user_id;
?>
```

The var_dump() should display a line like:

```
'wordpress_logged_in_ ....
```

If this cookie is not there WordPress will not see a logged in user.

How do you know you are logged in? Can you verify with the network tools of your browser that cookies are sent.

Comment: I am trying to implement it in wpdatatables plugin as php serialize array

Comment: Did var_dump( $_COOKIE ) display a cookie like 'wordpress_logged_in_ ...'?